# I can't get dataset from oracle database with web service

Tags: c#, web-services, oracle

I have this but DataSet won't fill

```
[WebMethod(Description = "")]
    public DataSet OracleDataset()
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=razvoj;User Id=kr;Password=kr;");

        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FBARZN", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }
```

What to do? Any solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what libraries are you using? ODP.NET, Oracle.Client by Microsoft or ?

Comment: Well do you [really need to return a dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188201/web-service-wcf-service-is-it-ever-better-to-return-a-dataset) ?

Comment: using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: Yes I need dataset. What else do you suggest?

Comment: I solved it.
I have used OleDbDataAdapter instead of OracleDataAdapter.